# How to Start Service and Stop Service Based on Time Interval in android

Tags: android

Hi Friends I need to Start Service Every Day Morning 6 AM and Need to Stop Service  Every Day 8 AM,please any one help me how to achieve that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a **BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
            {
                // get the current time here and start/stop your sevice depend on the time
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou..but here intent.getAction() how can i specify specified time

Comment: intent.getAction() does not give you the time.
To get the current hour you could use `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` for example.

Comment: if datetime.datetime.now().time() > datetime.time(6,0):
  # today, it's after 6 o'clock

Comment: @awk am sorry, i cant approve your update because he must use something that works outside the activity

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with the help of AlarmManager

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}



public void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar cal1,String name)
{

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
     intent.putExtra("name", name);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    long interval = cal1.getTimeInMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Interval=" + interval, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d("debug", "" + interval);
    Log.d("debug", "Current miliseconds =" + c.getTimeInMillis());

    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}   
}
```

Here is the class

You can directly set the alarm by using this class
(Do not forget to include receiver in AndroidManifest.xml)

Hope this will help you